# Is it a good idea to have a method that starts with get without being an accessor?

Tags: java, coding-standards, naming

Let's say you implement an interface like:

```
public interface Example {
  InputStream getThatContent();
}
```

In this case there is no property, and the implementation may also have side effects (it can open a new InputStream).

This is happening also in other API, like JDBC:

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url,
                       String user,
                       String password)
                                throws SQLException
```

The method starts with get, and actually creates a new connection, so I'm wondering, is the getter/setter method naming convention valid only in POJO classes? Or in all Java classes?

Comment: You *can* do whatever you want.  Whether it's a good idea is more complicated, though.

Comment: What's wrong with choosing another name, like `fetchThatContent`?

Comment: Nothing wrong about it, I'm just wondering whether it violates some naming convention or not. If so, why does Java JDBC API violates that too?

Comment: [The great thing about standards is that there are so many of them.](https://xkcd.com/927/)

Comment: @thermz It depends on what you consider a convention. But my guess is that *yes*, a typical Java programmer who has at least some basic experience, would be surprised if a method looks like a getter but actually has observable side effects. However, I would argue that the JDBC API method you showed does not actually look like a getter, because it's `static`.

Comment: You said it yourself in your question: this method "creates a new connection," so why not call the method `createConnection()`, since that's what it actually does?

Comment: @RobertHarvey probably my english is bad and I was unclear: that one is just an example of the JDBC Java standard library API that apparently violates the naming convention. It's not my API.

Comment: You could have a method getOut() without there being such a thing as out but only the absence of being in.

Comment: @JeffO: I find the idea of naming a method `getOut()` strangely satisfying.   You can execute it when you need a vacation.

Comment: `AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()` starts with `get` and obviously mutates state...

Comment: I believe this is a valid question (even more in this community). There is no need to close this question.

Comment: Thank you @Loa, my english is not that good and you're welcome to correct me, but I really believe that this question can be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The popular and accepted convention in the Java community about naming getters(1):**

- When you want to expose private members and comply with encapsulation you should not make said members public but instead write setters and getters and that setters should be named `setX(Type value)` and getters should be named `Type getX()`.

**That's all.**

- **The convention doesn't prohibit non-getters from beginning with the prefix "get".**
- A method like `getFullName()` could return `firstName+" "+LastName` even if that no class variable called `fullName` is part of the state.
- The convention doesn't state that methods beginning with the prefix "get" must not have side-effects. For example I could write to a log file inside a getter.

**Clarifying what is a POJO and what's not:**

A class using `java.util.Collection` continues to be a POJO because `java.util.Collection` is part of JSE. A class is not a POJO when it uses JEE or some external framework or annotations.

(1) Meaning by getter a method that returns the value of a class' private member.

- **Is it a good idea to have a method like** `getFullName()` **when the class has no** `fullName` **member?**

IMO it is. Besides, there's no way the consumer of a compiled class that has a `getFullName()` method would know whether or not the class has a member called `fullName`?

Answer (score 2):

When I see the get prefix I take it to mean exposed state until the code proves otherwise.  Whither that state is new or old doesn't concern me.

If your building me something that is mine to own, hold, close, etc. then the name I expect is thingBuilder.

It's impossible to tell you which is correct if you don't tell me who owns the input stream.  I'm saying if the caller is meant to own it use builder.

Otherwise use get to show you own this exposed state.  This makes you a value object.  Don't use get if that's not what you are.

Comment: I like your suggestion, and it defintively makes sense, however I was wondering if using the get prefix in these situations means to break a standard naming convention or it doesn't.

Comment: Please note edit

Answer (score 0):

It is a good idea when the external usage is similar to a getter.  Two primary forms come to mind.

If the information that is being provided is rendered and not stored

```
Class Rectangle
    {

int height = 3;
    int length = 4;



    getArea(){
        return height * length;
    }

    getPerimeter(){
        return 2 * ( height + length );
    }
}
```

If the method is returning a new object from a factory class

Note:  Apparently numbering a list breaks how code formatting works